# tcpdump prints nothing while trying to listen communication with sip server

Tags: linux, sip, tcpdump

The following command

```
sudo tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -i eth0 port 5060
```

works and prints incoming SIP messages.

Now I want to see entire communication and entering the IP address of the SIP server:

```
sudo tcpdump -nqt -s 0 -A -i eth0 host 208.73.146.95
```

and it prints nothing.

Why?

Comment: Maybe the SIP server IP is not the same as the RTP server IP? When you sniff on 5060 and it works can you see the `208.73.146.95` there?

Answer (score 1):

I think your interface might not be in promiscuous mode. Without this, you can only sniff traffic that comes from your interface or is addressed to it. For enabling promiscuous mode run this command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

I hope this will solve your problem.